# How do I run 2 processes in the return of a Django view?

Tags: python, django, django-views

I have a django site - does stuff..  when the print button is pressed I need it to run a def()  and then return to home

```
return view_xlsx(request, xlspath)
return render(request, 'webpage/HomePage.html', {'last_update': lastupdted})
```

How can I do both Run the view_xlsx ( which downloads in browser) and then return home?

I have tried

```
return view_xlsx(request, xlspath), render(request, 'webpage/HomePage.html', {'last_update': lastupdted})
```

and

```
        try:
            return view_xlsx(request, xlspath)
        finally:
            return render(request, 'website/HomePage.html', {'last_update': lastupdted})
```

They both work independently of each other, but wont seem to work together.  Thoughts ?

edit

```
def view_xlsx(request, xlspath):
    filename = xlspath.replace('\\', '/')
    name = filename.split('/')[-1]
    if os.path.exists(filename):
        response = FileResponse(open(filename, 'rb'), content_type='application/xlsx')
        response['Content-Disposition'] = f'inline; filename={name}'  # user will be prompted display the PDF in the browser
        # response['Content-Disposition'] = f'filename={name}'  # user will be prompted display the PDF in the browser
        return response
    else:
        return HttpResponseNotFound('Cannot find the XLS')
```

Comment: That's more complicated. You'd need to write some javascript on front-end side to make another call to the server

Comment: you could do it using use JavaScript but not using just python and part of it would be done through JS.

Answer (score 1):

You can't. It's a limitation of the HTTP protocol.

A typical work-around is to redirect to an html page which contains a link to the generated xls (or which will generate the xls "on the fly" if that's not too demanding). Your view will have fired up another process (or Celery task, etc.) to generate the xls, and will have created an object to represent the results, with an initial value/field saying "pending" or "ETA 4 mins".

You could build "your downloads" into the home page (if that's what it is), to allow retrieval once the (asynchronous) generation thereof has finished.

Another work-around is to use JS and Ajax to periodically ask if the xls is ready yet, and display a spinner or estimated wait time in the HTML page. If you do this you have to consider what happens if the user gets impatient and leaves the page.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to do this by defining a new combined function and calling that

```
return downloadandredirect(request, xlspath, lastupdated)

def downloadandredirect(request, xlspath, lastupdated):
    context = {'last_update': lastupdated}
    response = render(request, 'referrals/HomePage.html', context)
    return view_xlsx(request, xlspath)
```

Answer (score -1):

You can achieve this by using JavaScript to handle the download and then redirect the user to the home page. First, modify your `view_xlsx` function to return a JSON response containing the file URL instead of directly returning the file:

```py
from django.http import JsonResponse

def view_xlsx(request, xlspath):
    filename = xlspath.replace('\\', '/')
    name = filename.split('/')[-1]
    if os.path.exists(filename):
        file_url = f'/path/to/your/files/{name}'  # Replace this with the actual URL path to your files
        return JsonResponse({'file_url': file_url})
    else:
        return HttpResponseNotFound('Cannot find the XLS')
```

Next, create a new endpoint in your `urls.py` for the `view_xlsx` function:

```py
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    # ... other paths ...
    path('view_xlsx/', views.view_xlsx, name='view_xlsx'),
]
```

Now, in your template, add a JavaScript function to handle the download and redirect:

```html
<script>
function downloadAndRedirect() {
    fetch('/view_xlsx/')
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => {
            const link = document.createElement('a');
            link.href = data.file_url;
            link.download = 'your_file_name.xlsx';  // Replace this with the desired file name
            document.body.appendChild(link);
            link.click();
            document.body.removeChild(link);

            // Redirect to the home page
            window.location.href = '/';
        });
}
</script>
```

Finally, modify your print button to call the `downloadAndRedirect` function when clicked:

```html
<button onclick="downloadAndRedirect()">Print</button>
```

This way, when the user clicks the print button, the JavaScript function will download the file and then redirect the user to the home page.

Comment: There are other functions that happen  as part of the post that would get skipped this way.  The Post adds/updates rows in the model table and then output the xlsx and then return home - would this still call do this ?>